# Client side MVC instead of server side MVC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, backbone.js, ember.js

Instead of using server side MVC like Ruby, Python, PHP to build very complex websites, why should not we split our website into multiple modules, and build each with client side MVC like  backboneJS, EmberJS. In this case, we will use PHP / Ruby for creating webservices alone, which will serve data only.

Each module now act as small web app. If we link each other, they will perfectly look like a complex web app.

I visit many websites (like github, groupon, stackoverflow etc...) and they can be built or adopted to this approach. But i am not seeing this kind of approach. Does this approach has any problem on this kind of websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh yes. I got my answer.

> **From google groups:**
>   I think one of the reasons is javascriptless user-agents — i.e. search
>   engine crawlers and users with NoScript turned on.

I hope, these are real problems why websites still using Server Side MVCs.

When websites don't know target audience, they can't predict how well it will run on client side. So they should rely server to build much of their content.

And think, if stackoverflow was designed using client side MVC's to build much thier content, no one can't reach stackoverflow posts using google search.

> **From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) under "Search engine optimization" section:**
>   Because of the lack of JavaScript execution on crawlers of all popular
>   Web search engines, SEO has historically presented a problem for
>   public facing websites wishing to adopt the SPA model.

Answer (score 1):

*Was to long for a comment*

I guess the tricky part is indeed the point you mentioned

> f we link each other, they will perfectly look like a complex web app.

Because each MVC framework uses a different approach to tackle usual problems you have in modern web-apps, like ***routing***, ***data binding***, ***application state*** and ***rendering*** DOM elements, so I think you would end up having multiple frameworks doing tasks that overlap substantially, thus forcing you to deactivate or disable some of the built-in functionality of one or the other framework making your *frankenstein*-app :) very difficult to maintain.

A good example is jQuery-mobile & ember.js, both have a ***routing*** system, jQuery uses the DOM to hold ***state*** ember.js holds it's state completely in ***javascript*** which is much faster. I had a similar problem with a project using jQuery-mobile & ember.js and this forced me to decide for one of the routing systems, I took ember's and deactivated jQuery's wich then let with just a bunch of custom mobile-looking components on the side of jQuery-mobile. Finally I removed jQuery-mobile using ember.js only and CSS for the mobile-looking app.

If not because of a concrete requirement, IMHO your best bet is to have just ***one*** very good, flexible and opinionated framework (personally I prefer **ember.js**) and create the modules you mentioned with your only choice.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As of now we can say that most of the applications are forced to put in more effort in its UI/UX and hence the dependancy on server side is becoming very less.

I have personally used backbone for my latest work and this has been great. The speed of the entire application can be noticed from the beginning. Ive been using PHP for the past 3 years and i can definitely vouch that backbone and other MV* frameworks are better.

Combined with CSS frameworks such as bootstrap, backbone can be an extremely organised and elegant applications.

All said, getting your head around models,views,routers,collections can be a headache. This is something which has vast possibilities and its only getting started.

Ive compiled a tutorial based on lots of tutorials present and has published at http://goo.gl/nJumC.

So many video tutorials are also available.

Only per-requisite is that one should have good knowledge of javascript and jquery methods and functions. Beginner knowledge in these will only make your task of learning backbone difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the shift we are heading now; I am not really sure about you but I noticed far more Client Side MVC Web sites. Anyways, you can also take a look at this ....

http://backbonejs.org/#examples

in my view, except the learning curve, it is pretty neat to develop using Client MVC and Web APIs using JSON/REST